# Obtain FedAuth Cookie with RST token

Tags: javascript, adfs, sts, cookie

I've got a phone gap application which should contact ADFS with a RST to obtain a SAML token then should pass this token to STS to obtain a FedAuth Cookie which is finally used in the header of REST calls.

I'm contacting ADFS with this envelope:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://host/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-6a13a244-dac6-42c1-84c5-cbb345b0c4c4-1">
            <o:Username>myUser</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">myPassword</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
        <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
            <a:EndpointReference>
                <a:Address>https://host/adfs/ls</a:Address>
            </a:EndpointReference>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
        <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
        <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
        <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
    </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
```

this is the response that i obtain:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RSTRC/IssueFinal</a:Action>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2014-10-27T13:01:36.732Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2014-10-27T13:06:36.732Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
        <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
            <trust:Lifetime>
                <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-10-27T13:01:36.717Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-10-27T21:01:36.717Z</wsu:Expires>
            </trust:Lifetime>
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsa:Address>https://host/adfs/ls/</wsa:Address>
                </wsa:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <SecurityContextToken u:Id="_641d53b3-6cee-4817-968c-1e03fdd9a598-FEA940F2E5E8BD29F68ACF2E3319296A" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512">
                    <Identifier>urn:uuid:092f0aee-2e3a-4829-9b1e-3cf2547e5180</Identifier>
                    <Instance>urn:uuid:73679764-2488-4043-b5ad-515634acb8bc</Instance>
                    <Cookie xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security">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</Cookie>
                </SecurityContextToken>
            </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
            <trust:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</trust:TokenType>
            <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
            <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
        </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
</s:Body>
```

what should i do?

they told me i need to send this token to this url `https://host/_vti_bin/sts/spsecuritytokenservice.svc/cookie` to obtain the FedAuth Cookie, but i don't know how... i've wrote this function, but i always receive 400 bad request.

`token` is the content of tag `<Cookie>`, but i've also tried to pass the entire xml, or portions of it...

```
wsignin: function(token){
        console.log('start wsignin' );
        console.log('wsignin token:'+token );
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'https://host/_vti_bin/sts/spsecuritytokenservice.svc/cookie',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/soap+msbin1',
            type:'POST',
            'data':token,
            headers: {
                Accept : "application/soap+msbin1"
            },
            success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('done wsignin ' + result);
            },
            error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('error wsignin:' + jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log('complete wsignin ' + textStatus);

            }
        });
        console.log('end wsignin' );
    }
```

any help will be very appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Can you just submit form (make post-call) with "wa", "wresult", "wctx" fields to  /_trust/default.aspx  and receive cookie (as in standard SharePoint auth process)?

Comment: Did you find the solution , i have the same isssue here. and would please share how did you contact the ADFS ? thank  you

Comment: Please post solution if found!

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace SPClient
{
    class FedAuthUtility
    {
        public Cookie GetAuthCookie(String Url, String uname, String pswd)
        {

            CookieContainer CookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            Uri authServiceUri = new Uri(Url+ "/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx");
            HttpWebRequest spAuthReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(authServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest;
            spAuthReq.CookieContainer = CookieJar;
            spAuthReq.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/Login";
            spAuthReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            spAuthReq.Method = "POST";
            string envelope =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                + "<soap:Body>"
                + "<Login xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
                + "<username>{0}</username>"
                + "<password>{1}</password>"
                + "</Login>" + "</soap:Body>"
                + "</soap:Envelope>";
            string userName = uname;
            string password = pswd;
            envelope = string.Format(envelope, userName, password);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(spAuthReq.GetRequestStream());
            streamWriter.Write(envelope);
            streamWriter.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = spAuthReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Cookie returnValue = response.Cookies[0];
            response.Close();
            return returnValue;

        }

      public Cookie  GetAuthCookieWin(String Url)
        {

          Cookie cookie=new Cookie();
          HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( 
                        Url + "_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252FDefault%252Easpx&Source=%2FDefault.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;

                    // Provide a set of Windows credentials (default or explicit) 
                    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
                    request.Method = "GET";  

                    // Assign the CookieContainer object 
                    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();  
                     request.CookieContainer = cookies; 
                    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 

                    // Execute the HTTP request 
                    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; 
                    if (null != response) 
                    { 
                        // The following variable simply holds the FedAuth cookie value, but that value 
                        // is not used directly 
                        cookie = response.Cookies["FedAuth"]; 
                    }
                    return cookie;

        }
    }
}
```

I hope the attached code will be usefull. But you may turn this in to jquery call.

Comment: I think this think is incorrect. I am working on a similar project and if I attempt to hit Authentication.asmx for a claims based site then I get an error message :Site is not configured for Claims-based authentication

Comment: double check whether you have choosed claims based auth while creating the web app. you might be having it as classic mode.